# How to Group by column value in Pandas Data frame

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, data-science

I have pandas dataframe like this. I want group by App_Name in seperate variable

```
App_Name    Date        Response    Gross Revenue
com.apple.tiles2    2018-10-13  3748.723574 24133394
com.orange.thescore 2018-10-13  2034.611964 8273607
com.number.studio   2018-10-13  1807.756545 33736740
com.orange.thescore 2018-10-14  4671.930435 38575556
com.number.studio   2018-10-14  3533.461547 38726087
com.banana.com      2018-10-14  2920.33747  86230313
com.apple.tiles2    2018-10-15  3986.434851 35928884
com.number.studio   2018-10-15  2044.759823 76526368
com.apple.tiles2    2018-10-16  2610.214035 30611434
com.alpha.studio    2018-10-16  1731.429858 11643154
com.banana.com      2018-10-16  1601.387403 13781285
com.alpha.studio    2018-10-17  2769.373388 13198984
com.banana.com      2018-10-17  2205.359489 21974901
com.orange.thescore 2018-10-17  1820.852862 7565015
com.alpha.studio    2018-10-18  2784.822039 24217875
com.banana.com      2018-10-18  2545.899329 28361412
com.orange.thescore 2018-10-18  2052.207745 7544861
```

I want to group data by App_Name and stored in sepearte list or dataframe for each App_Name, something like this given below:

```
App_Name    Date        Response    Gross Revenue
com.alpha.studio    2018-10-16  1731.429858 11643154
com.alpha.studio    2018-10-17  2769.373388 13198984
com.alpha.studio    2018-10-18  2784.822039 24217875

App_Name    Date        Response    Gross Revenue
com.apple.tiles2    2018-10-13  3748.723574 24133394
com.apple.tiles2    2018-10-15  3986.434851 35928884
com.apple.tiles2    2018-10-16  2610.214035 30611434

App_Name    Date        Response    Gross Revenue
com.banana.com      2018-10-14  2920.33747  86230313
com.banana.com      2018-10-16  1601.387403 13781285
com.banana.com      2018-10-17  2205.359489 21974901
com.banana.com      2018-10-18  2545.899329 28361412

App_Name    Date        Response    Gross Revenue
com.number.studio   2018-10-14  3533.461547 38726087
com.number.studio   2018-10-13  1807.756545 33736740
com.number.studio   2018-10-15  2044.759823 76526368

App_Name    Date        Response    Gross Revenue
com.orange.thescore 2018-10-13  2034.611964 8273607
com.orange.thescore 2018-10-14  4671.930435 38575556
com.orange.thescore 2018-10-17  1820.852862 7565015
com.orange.thescore 2018-10-18  2052.207745 7544861
```

Comment: `df.groupby('App_Name')`?

Comment: I'd like to know how this question has 4 upvotes in 3 minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) object to dictionary of DataFrames:

```
d = dict(tuple(df.groupby('App_Name')))

print (d['com.alpha.studio'])
            App_Name        Date     Response     Gross  Revenue
9   com.alpha.studio  2018-10-16  1731.429858  11643154      NaN
11  com.alpha.studio  2018-10-17  2769.373388  13198984      NaN
14  com.alpha.studio  2018-10-18  2784.822039  24217875      NaN
```

EDIT:

```
d1 = {}
for k, v in d.items():
     d1[k] = v['Gross Revenue'].rolling(2).mean()
```

Comment: do you have any idea why `dict(df.groupby('App_Name')` is giving an `TypeError: attribute of type 'str' is not callable` error? It's *very* strange

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - Sorry, not idea.

Comment: @ jezrael I want to calculate the rolling mean for gross revenue and store separately date frame with calculated mean and corresponding date.
can please help in it

Comment: What is formula for standard DataFrame?

Comment: @jezrael rolling_mean = com.alpha.studio['Gross Revenue'].rolling(2).mean()

Excepted format
         Date        Gross Revenue
         1             NaN
   2018-10-16    3352.5
   2018-10-17    3245.5
   2018-10-18    2583.0

Comment: @hamsa - check edited answer. Is possible loop by each DataFrame, caunt values and append back.